n-ary Entity-Relationship for Modified Chen notation
Given is this ER diagram, with the following information:
A single actor may receive multiple awards for a specific, single movie. An actor receives such a single award for exactly one movie though. A single award for a single
movie can be awarded to one or multiple actors.

I don't understand how to specify the cardinalities in Modified Chen notation.
